# Homotopy group of noncompact space

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence

Conceptually, how do we understand why the homotopy group of noncompact space is well-defined:
$$
\pi_k(M)
$$
for $\pi_k(M)$ as the homotopy class of the compact sphere $S^k$ to the noncompact space $M$?

For example, many such calculations can be done, but it becomes a calculation of homotopy group of compact spheres. e.g. the $O(3,1)$ is a noncompact Lie group, but we can compute the homotopy group as
$$
\pi_1(O(3,1)) = \pi_1(O(3)) \times  \pi_1(O(1)) = \pi_1(SO({3})) \times  \pi_1( \mathbb{Z}/2 )  = \pi_1(S^3/\mathbb{Z}/2) \times  \pi_1( \mathbb{Z}/2 )= \mathbb{Z}/2.
$$
Which is related to the [homotopy group of spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres).

1. But how to argue such a homotopy class of the compact space to the noncompact space can be defined? I am not sure what is the best way to imagine how a sphere to wrap around the noncompact space that can be well-defined?
2. Is this, and, why is this homotopy class an abelian group? (finite or infinite abelian group?)

Comment: If you look up the definition of [homotopy groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group), at no point is the target space assumed to be compact.

Comment: The concept of homotopy group is defined for all topological spaces. That includes noncompact ones.

Comment: Do you guys feel intuitive to think of the homotopy class of the compact space to the noncompact space ? I mean, give some logical intuitions how this wrapping around the noncompact space is done?

Comment: Certainly the image of any map $S^k \to M$ will be compact, so each such map only "detects" a compact portion of $M$. Different maps can detect different parts of $M$, though. Consider the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{Z}$, for example, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is embedded as the integers on the horizontal axis.

Comment: One usually develops intuition by working through examples. Did you compute any examples of homotopy groups?